# How to calculate a static average value of all rows in a Table to compare individual row values to in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, average

I need to calculate a static average value of all rows in a Table to compare individual row values against. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT i.ITEM_NAME, i.ITEM_PRICE
  FROM ITEM i
  GROUP BY i.ITEM_NAME, i.ITEM_PRICE
  HAVING i.ITEM_PRICE > AVG(i.ITEM_PRICE)
  ORDER BY i.ITEM_PRICE DESC, i.ITEM_NAME ASC;
```

My problem is that the average that is being used to compare a row's `ITEM_PRICE` against is being calculated for only said row's `ITEM_PRICE` (an average of one number). Is there anyway within this query that I could obtain a static average of all of the rows' `ITEM_PRICE`s to compare the individual `ITEM_PRICE` for each row against? I think the problem may be in the way the `GROUP BY` correlates the values, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only want to calculate the average of all rows, you could forego grouping, and just use a `WHERE` clause to compare the price against average. Code would be something like:

```
select item_name, item_price
from item
where item_price > (select avg(item_price) from item)
order by item_price desc, item_name asc
```

Of course, this assumes that you have only one row for one `item_name`.